# Terraform - Multiple accounts with multiple environments (regions)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, environment, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code

I am developing the infrastructure (IaC) I want to have in **AWS** with **Terraform**. To test, I am using an EC2 instance.

This code has to be able to be deployed **across multiple accounts** and **multiple regions (environments) per developer **. This is an example:

**account-999**

```
developer1: us-east-2
developer2: us-west-1
developerN: us-east-1
```

**account-666**:

```
Staging: us-east-1
Production: eu-west-2
```

I've created two `.tfvars` variables, `account-999.env.tfvars` and `account-666.env.tfvars` with the following content:

- `profile="account-999"` and  `profile="account-666"` respectively

This is my `main.tf` which contains the aws provider with the EC2 instance:

```
provider "aws" {
  version = "~> 2.0"
  region  = "us-east-1"
  profile = var.profile
}

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"]
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = "t3.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

And the `variable.tf` file:

```
variable "profile" {
  type=string
}

variable "region" {
  description = "Region by developer"
  type = map
  default = {
    developer1 = "us-west-2"
    developer2 = "us-east-2"
    developerN = "ap-southeast-1"
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure if I'm managing it well. For example, the `region` variable only contains the values of the `account-999` account. How can I solve that?
On the other hand, with this structure, would it be possible to implement modules?

Comment: Regions can be solved best with modules and provider aliases, especially if you are using 0.13 with the new meta-argument features for modules.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `provider alias` to accomplish this. More info about provider aliases can be found [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html).

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "west"
  region = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
  provider = aws.west
  # ...
}
```

Another way to look at is, is by using `terraform workspaces`. Here is an example:

```
terraform workspace new account-999
terraform workspace new account-666
```

Then this is an example of your aws credentials file:

```
[account-999]
aws_access_key_id=xxx
aws_secret_access_key=xxx

[account-666]
aws_access_key_id=xxx
aws_secret_access_key=xxx
```

A reference to that account can be used within the provider block:

```
provider "aws" {
    region  = "us-east-1"
    profile = "${terraform.workspace}"
}
```

You could even combine both methods!